# ASP.NET MVC4 Entity Framework db.SaveChanges() Condition not working

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working on a project in ASP.NET MVC4 with entity framework.
Here is the problem, i would like my code to send back a different Json object
depending on if the Db.savechanges worked or not !

Ive been doing some debug with the console and it seems that I always get false from the else part of my IF and it never goes in the actual condition even if the condition is ok. Hard to explain but easy to understand with code so here it goes.

Code from my Controller sending True or false json object to my javascript

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Enregistrer_Inscription(InscriptionPost inscPost)
    {

            NoirEtOrEntities db = new NoirEtOrEntities();
            Inscription insc = new Inscription()
            {
                inscriptionNom = inscPost.nomJ,
                inscriptionPrenom = inscPost.prenomJ,
                inscriptionDateNaissance = inscPost.DateNaissance,
                inscriptionDate = DateTime.Now,
                inscriptionCategory = inscPost.Category,
                inscriptionDivision = inscPost.Division,
                inscriptionStatut = inscPost.Statut,
                inscriptionTaille = inscPost.Taille,
                inscriptionSexe = inscPost.Sexe,
                inscriptionEcole = inscPost.Ecole,
                inscriptionAgeSept = inscPost.AgeSept,
                inscriptionNiveauScolaire = inscPost.NiveauScolaire,
                inscriptionAdresseJ = inscPost.AdresseJ,
                inscriptionVilleJ = inscPost.VilleJ,
                inscriptionCodePostalJ = inscPost.CodePostalJ,
                inscriptionCourrielJ = inscPost.CourrielJ,
                inscriptionTelephoneJ = inscPost.TelephoneJ,
                inscriptionNomP = inscPost.nomP,
                inscriptionPrenomP = inscPost.prenomP,
                inscriptionAdresseP = inscPost.AdresseP,
                inscriptionVilleP = inscPost.VilleP,
                inscriptionCodePostalP = inscPost.CodePostalP,
                inscriptionCourrielP = inscPost.CourrielP,
                inscriptionTelephoneP = inscPost.TelephoneP,
                inscriptionNomM = inscPost.nomM,
                inscriptionPrenomM = inscPost.prenomM,
                inscriptionAdresseM = inscPost.AdresseM,
                inscriptionVilleM = inscPost.VilleM,
                inscriptionCodePostalM = inscPost.CodePostalM,
                inscriptionCourrielM = inscPost.CourrielM,
                inscriptionTelephoneM = inscPost.TelephoneM,
                inscriptionNotes = inscPost.Notes,

            };
        try
        {
            db.Inscription.Add(insc);            
            db.SaveChanges();
            if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
            {
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success = false }); 
            }

        }            
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }                       
    }
}
```

Here is my Jquery code

```
 success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.success);
                if (data.success == true) {
                    console.log("succ");
                    console.log(data);
                    alertify.success("Formulaire recu avec succès", 5000);
                    Vider_Champs()
                }
                else {
                    console.log("nope");
                    console.log(data);
                    alertify.error("Le formulaire comporte des erreurs", 5000);
                }                       
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
                alertify.error("Le formulaire comporte des erreurs", 5000);
            }
        });
    }
```

So the problem is on code :        `if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)`
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `db.SaveChanges()` twice:

```
db.SaveChanges();              // save changes to database
if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)      // save changes once again
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

First time you call the method the changes are saved and there is nothing to save next time you call it. Instead, save the result of the call in variable and use it in the next line:

```
int result = db.SaveChanges();
if (result > 0)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Comment: just tried it and its not working ! still not going in the IF, it goes over it and return false from the else

Comment: @JeffLA Are you sure it is running in else statement? Another case where false is returned is when `DbEntityValidationException` is thrown during the save method call

Comment: your right ! it is because of this exception ! but i dont really understand it

Comment: post the detail of this DbEntityValidationException

Comment: It might be something wrong in your 'Inscription' type, make sure any column value mismatched with the model.Also see the detail of exception so you would have a better guess what is wrong with this 'Inscription' fields.